# on "click" event both the input values should display. Right now it is only accepting last input box value only

Tags: reactjs

On "click" event both the input values should display. Right now it is only accepting last input box value only. Also it says A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled.

````
```
 import React,{useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState({firstName:'',lastName:''})
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState([]);

const eventNames = (event )=> {
setName( event.target.value)
}

// const eventLastNames = (event )=> {
// setName({...name, lastName: event.target.value})
// }

const namesClick = () => {
  setNewName((oldItem) => {
    return (
      [...oldItem, name]
      );
  })
}


  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h1> useState trial demo</h1>
    <input type="text" value={name.firstName} 
    onChange={eventNames} 
    placeholder="Enter your name" />
    
     <input type="text" value={name.lastName}
     onChange ={eventNames}
     placeholder="Enter your name" />
     <button onClick={namesClick}>Submit </button>

     {/* <h2> Your name is : {name.firstName} </h2> */}
     {/* <h2> Your name is : {name.lastName} </h2> */}

     {newName.map((val) => {
       return <h2>{val}</h2>
     })}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on `eventNames` you assign last event value from any input. You should add property name to inputs and then in `eventNames`method use name's property to assign value in the object.

This works:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState({ firstName: "", lastName: "" });
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState([]);

  const eventNames = (event) => {
    setName({ ...name, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  // const eventLastNames = (event )=> {
  // setName({...name, lastName: event.target.value})
  // }

  const namesClick = () => {
    setNewName((oldItem) => {
      return [...oldItem, name];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> useState trial demo</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        value={name.firstName}
        onChange={eventNames}
        placeholder="Enter your name"
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        name="lastName"
        value={name.lastName}
        onChange={eventNames}
        placeholder="Enter your name"
      />
      <button onClick={namesClick}>Submit </button>

      {/* <h2> Your name is : {name.firstName} </h2> */}
      {/* <h2> Your name is : {name.lastName} </h2> */}

      {newName.map((val) => {
        return Object.values(val).map((_val) => <h2>{_val}</h2>);
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Finally I used this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-cloud-9xn80?file=/src/App.js) to test it

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

You overwrite the `name` state with the same value, or rather, the last name overwrites the first name and you end up with a string versus object with `firstName` and `lastName` keys.

You also don't map the `newName` array correctly in the render.

## Solution

1. Provide a name attribute to the inputs so you can correctly update state.
2. Use a functional state update to copy previous state.
3. Map the `newName` first and last name properties

Code

```
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState({ firstName: "", lastName: "" });
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState([]);

  const eventNames = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target; // <-- get name and value from event
    setName(state => ({
      ...state, // <-- copy state
      [name]: value, // <-- overwrite field
    }));
  };

  const namesClick = () => {
    setNewName((oldItem) => {
      return [...oldItem, name];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> useState trial demo</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="firstName" // <-- provide name matching state property
        value={name.firstName}
        onChange={eventNames}
        placeholder="Enter your name"
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        name="lastName" // <-- provide name matching state property
        value={name.lastName}
        onChange={eventNames}
        placeholder="Enter your name"
      />
      <button onClick={namesClick}>Submit </button>

      <h2> Your first name is : {name.firstName} </h2>
      <h2> Your last name is : {name.lastName} </h2>

      {newName.map(({ firstName, lastName }) => { // <-- access properties
        return <h2>{[firstName, lastName].join(' ')}</h2>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit on-click-event-both-the-input-values-should-display-right-now-it-is-only-acce]